# Use file from lib and page

Tags: javascript, firefox, sdk

I wanna use one log-function to lib and page scripts. Lib need require, but I don't wanna include it in page only for it. I have only file with only function and want that lib could use it.

Function:

```
function log( caller, text )
{
    console.log( callerName + ': ' + text );
}
```

Trying to include in lib:

```
tabs.on('activate', function(tab) {
    tab.attach({
        contentScriptFile: require( 'sdk/self' ).data.url( 'page/log.js' )
    });
    log( 'caller', 'text' )
});
```

Thx.